# how to view contents of asm diskgroup contained file?

Tags: linux, oracle11g, filesystems, cat

I've just transferred my oracle 11g 11.2.0.4 DB to ASM and I want to look 
at the contents of some of the files. At first I tried using ASMCMD but then realized it doesn't have such a command, and when trying to read from the diskgroup path it returns "no such file...".
is there any way to accomplish that?

thnx in advance, 
Jack.

Comment: What does ASM stand for, the way you're using it?  The [tag:assembly] tag is for assembly *language*, a text representation of CPU instructions like `add eax, [rdi]`.  That doesn't appear to make sense but I don't know how to retag this question.

Comment: ASM = Automated Storage Management. Essentially it is Oracle's take on logical volume management. That said, what is the purpose of looking "at the contents of some of the files"? Pretty much everything stored in ASM, other than a couple of configuration files, is in a binary format that you can't read anyway. What are you looking for?

Comment: @pmdba I have .ora files in asm, and in regular fs I can read them. Is there any way I can do that when the're in ASM too?

Comment: @PeterCordes I tried to tag ASM but the website system took it as assembly. thanks for noticing, I've revised the tags to not include this one.

Comment: @jackInTheBox ASM doesn't really have the utilities for that built in. For most things you'd have to make a copy of the file to a traditional file system and then view it. Typically .ora configuration files are not placed in ASM, which is primarily for data files, backups, flashback archives, the spfile, and other binary/automatically managed files; they reside under $ORACLE_HOME in a traditional file system (e.g. $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin). What version of Oracle are you using, and how does it access these files at all, since there's no file system path to reach them in ASM?

Comment: @pmdba I created a DB in fs then moved all its files to ASM, data, control, logs, temp and spfile. the spfile is the file I was trying to read after I recreated it in ASM from the fs pfile. my oracle version is 11.2.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the spfile is the file I was trying to read after I recreated it in ASM from the fs pfile.

The spfile is a binary format and can't be read directly. You can look at the settings through use of the "show parameter" command in sqlplus, or the v$parameter view in the database, or you can "create pfile from spfile" in sqlplus to make a text copy of it to a normal file system for viewing - just be sure to use a non-standard file name for the new pfile/copy and not to overwrite your existing "live" pfile, which should be a pointer to the spfile location in ASM.

- https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/persistent-initialization-parameters
- https://www.thegeekdiary.com/oracle-database-basics-about-pfile-and-spfile/
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/create006.htm#ADMIN11124